# Crear varias datagridview con un solo botón

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Tengo 4 listas que se llenan con entradas de usuario, estas me llenan los datos columna a columna en un datagridview que llame datagridview1, lo tengo predefinido en mi form principal, tengo un botón que me muestra todos los valores seleccionados por el usuario en esa datagrid, mi problema es que quiero generar varias datagrid view con otro botón(primero una, luego otra y luego otra), principalmente para poder comparar las opciones seleccionadas por el usuario para depsues mandarlas a un Excel, lo que no logro visualizar es como hacer el ciclo o como definir varias y hacer referencias entre las datagrids para generar diferentes y al final todas poder visualizarlas.

Parte de mi código va así :

```cs
//En este punto los valores ya se encuentran cargados en las listas Valores, cantidades, codigos y proces.
//Al evento de presionar el boton...
private void btAddOp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
//Aqui agrego tantas filas como  datos disponibles
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(valores.Count()); 

//Con este ciclo relleno cada columna de la tabla
for (int i = 0; i < valores.Count; i++){
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = valores[i];
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = cantidades[i];
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = codigos[i];
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = proces[i];
    }
}
```

Y para poder generar tabla a tabla creo que sería algo similar a esto:

```
private void btAddOp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
........
........
........
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv = dataGridView1;
??????;
```

Aquí es donde ya me pierdo y requiero una guía o un pequeño ejemplo, aun no comprendo del todo los conceptos de datagrid, datatable y dataset que creo que me vendrían de perlas aquí, tengo poco con C# y lo aprendo por mi cuenta, cualquier guía para saber cómo continuar o algún ejemplo será bienvenido y muy apreciado.
PD. Perdón si estoy repitiendo la pregunta no es mi intención hacer SPAM he buscado en ingles y en español pero no logro entender como poder seguir.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Que es un [DataGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8)?

Estas son sus [diferencias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/differences-between-the-windows-forms-datagridview-and-datagrid-controls) respecto a su sucesor el `DataGridView`

Un resumen claro del link que te ofrecí es que el control `DataGrid` es la versión arcaica del control `DataGridView`

> DataSet y DataTable

El `DataSet` vendria a ser lo que se conoce como una base de datos. se pueden guardar `tablas`, `relaciones`, `rules`, `datatables`...etc

El `DataTable` es simplemente una tabla que almacena información de alguna `query` o de forma manual.

Ahora respecto a tu problema, lo que vos queres (Según entendí) es crear controles `DataGridView` `n` de veces con un solo boton.

Para lograr esto vamos a ir paso a paso.

> Importamos la libreria de forms para acceder a los controles

```
//Al inicio de tu codigo.
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

> Declaramos una nueva instancia del control como si fuese una variable

```
//Esta declaración la instanciaremos dentro del for para que se vuelva reutilizable y dinamica.
DataGridView _dgv1 = new DataGridView();
```

Dato: Gracias a esta declaracion a nivel del bloque `for` podemos reutilizarla tantas veces la necesitemos, si en vez de hacer esto la instanciabamos fuera del bloque siempre íbamos a estar trabajando con el mismo `DataGridView` y por ende íbamos a tener 1 solo control visible. Te invito a que hagas la prueba para que comprendas mas a fondo la importancia de las declaraciones.

> En la función

```
//Los parametros son el entero que servira de veces para recorrer el for y 
//un form para que se pueda reutilizar en todos los forms que quieras.
void GenerarDgv(int _CantidadDeDgv, Form _this)
    {
        //un for que recorra la cantidad de veces que se requiera.
        for (int i = 0; i < _CantidadDeDgv; i++)
        {
            Declaramos el control.
            DataGridView _dgv1 = new DataGridView();

            //Especificamos en que form crearemos el control
            _dgv1.Parent = _this;
            //Asignamos un nombre para el control
            _dgv1.Name = "_dataGridView" + i;
            //Le asignamos la ubicación en el form (Point pide dos parámetros, ambos enteros. el primero de  de posición  del eje "X" y el segundo de posición del eje "Y"
            _dgv1.Location = new Point(i * 25, 25);
            //Tamaño de ancho por largo del DataGridView
            _dgv1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        }
    }
```

Dato: Como veras, las propiedades del `DataGridview` que llame son las mismas que las del panel  de propiedades que le asignas desde el diseño del `form`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como te lo remarco `Name`, `Location` y `Size` son las propiedades que use desde el código para darle un formato. Así como esas podes usar todas las que aparecen en la lista para manipularlo al 100% hasta satisfacer tus necesidades.

> Llamamos a la función desde el evento click del botón

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //En este caso le asigno que se creen 5 DataGridView's y el form que le asigno es el actual mediante la palabra reservada [this] que lo que hace es reverenciar a la clase actual. osea, al form que se esta programando en otras palabras...
        GenerarDgv(5, this);
    }
```

Y con eso ya vas crear la cantidad de `DataGridView` que quieras dentro de un mismo `form`. ahora tu trabajo es ajustar a tu medida `Location` y `Size` para que encaje de acuerdo a tus demandas en tu trabajo.